# I am writing a sorting function to sort the char type list in ascending order, and return the number of counting if there any swaps

Tags: c++, sorting

Here is what I wrote, I am learning c++ applied programming this year, and it is a little bit hard as I am an engineer, I really need some help...

first, I wrote a swap function wich is bool type:

```
bool swap(char &list[], int &size)
{
        bool found = false;
        for(int i = 0; int < size; i++)
           if(strcmp(list[i],list[i+1] > 0)
           {
                 swap(list[i],list[i+1]);
                 found = true;
                 return found;
           }
           else
           {
                 found = false;
                 return found;
           }
}
```

Second, I wrote a sorting function as below:

```
int sort(char list[], int size)
{
       for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
          for(int count = 0;; count++）
             swap(list[j],size);
             if(swap() = true)
             {
                  return count;
             }
             else
             {
                  return 0;
             }
}
```

I don't know if it is correct(I guess not), please help me with this one, I am doing some practicing questions for my final exam on next Tuesday.I really appreciate!

Comment: Definitely not correct as-is. This: `if(swap() = true)` won't compile, for starters.

Comment: Then what should do? should I change it to if(swap() == true)? or I am still missing something here?

Comment: How can you not know if it is correct or not? Run it and see if it sorts a list or not.

Comment: @takendarkk as I said, I am doing some c++ questions for reviewing this subject, the questions is not asking to write a whole program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort an array of characters in ascending order, there are several attempts to do this (Check out [Wikipedia - Sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)). The simplest of all is probably the Bubble Sort algorithm.

The Swap()-function takes two parameters, and changes their value. Therefore in C++ this can easily be achieved via references:

```
void swap(char &a, char &b) {
    char tmp;

    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

The function won't return anything, as input parameters will be written to.

Your sort()-function will take an array of characters, the length of that array and will return the number of swaps that have taken place. (The return part really is optional, but you said you wanted it in your program). A Bubble Sort will look like this:

```
int bubble_sort(char array[], int size) {
    int total_swaps = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            if(array[i] < array[j]) {
                //Here a swap is necessary
                swap(array[i], array[j]);
                total_swaps++;
            }
        }
    }

    return total_swaps;
}
```

If you call this function on an array of characters the elements of the array will be rearranged in ascending order.

If you have any questions left, feel free to ask!

Cheers,
lindebear